# MySQL 'bind_param' statement doesn't seem to work - UserCake cutomization

Tags: php, mysql, sql, registration, usercake

So I am working on a project using UserCake. I have added fields to the 'users' table. So far, everything works great. The issue I am having is when you register, it returns successful but the SQL statement did not put any of the form data into the database.

So far, I have been successful at adding the necessary fields and I am able to pull data from those fields however, I am not able to push data to the database.  I have a feeling it has to do with the bind_param statement, but I am not sure. Here's what I am dealing with:

EDIT 9/30 5pm >>> Only issue at this point is that the data is not being put into the table.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$db_table_prefix."users (
                password,
                email,
                activation_token,
                last_activation_request,
                lost_password_request,
                active,
                title,
                sign_up_stamp,
                last_sign_in_stamp,
                company,
                address_1,
                address_2,
                city,
                state,
                zip,
                paid,
                first_name,
                last_name
                )
                VALUES (
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                '".time()."',
                '0',
                ?,
                'New Member',
                '".time()."',
                '0',
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                '0',
                ?,
                ?
                )");

            $stmt->bind_param("sssisssssiiss", $secure_pass, $this->clean_email, $this->activation_token, $this->user_active, $this->company, $this->address_1, $this->address_2, $this->city, $this->state, $this->zip, $this->first_name, $this->last_name);
            $stmt->execute();
            print_r($stmt);
            $inserted_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
            $stmt->close();
```

EDIT >>> Solved empty array issue

I am calling the new user like this:
    $user = new User($password, $email, $token, $activationRequest, $passwordRequest, $active, $title, $signUp, $signIn, $company, $address_1, $address_2, $city, $state, $zip, $paid, $first_name, $last_name);

EDIT >>>
TABLE `uc_users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(225) NOT NULL,

`email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,

`activation_token` varchar(225) NOT NULL,

`last_activation_request` int(11) NOT NULL,

`lost_password_request` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,

`active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,

`title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,

`sign_up_stamp` int(11) NOT NULL,

`last_sign_in_stamp` int(11) NOT NULL,

`company` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,

`address_1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`address_2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`state` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`zip` int(5) NOT NULL,

`paid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,

`first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

Comment: Column 'company' cannot be null, is your company field set ?

Comment: Yes, I have a value in each of the variables listed as '?'

Comment: but `$this -> company` is null, as I see in error, can you do `var_dump($this)` and see the value of company variable ?

Comment: Just added the print_r($user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field `Company` on your table not allowing `NULL` values, but Your'e sending it `null` as I see in Your question ( print_r($this) section ).

So You have 2 ways to solve this problem,

1. If you really need for company, set Company field as required and check it during the validation (after sending query), this will keep you away from such problems.
2. Otherwise alter your `company` field in database, and allow NULLs for it.

Comment: I understand that, and it isn't required. However, I am typing in a company name. Even still first_name, last_name, etc. are all empty as well.

Comment: Can you provide the DDL of your table please?

Comment: I'm not 100% positive what you mean by DDL, but I'm using MySQL.. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I know, I mean the create table query of users table

Comment: Okay that's what I was thinking. I just put it up there

Comment: this is paradox for me, the exception you've wrote is `[error] => Column 'company' cannot be null )` but the company field accepts nulls  in table.. can you try run one more time and see the error, is that same ??

Comment: Okay so I got a little further. In the __construct funtion, I need to do this with each variable: `$this->first_name = $first_name;` So now, when I `print_r($user)` the array is full. However, it is still not putting the data into the database.

Comment: I just checked, Had to change the `?,` for paid to `'0',` and I fixed `bind_param()` to match. I am now getting this error:
`mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 12 [field_count] => 0 [errno] => 2031 [error] => No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement [error_list] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [errno] => 2031 [sqlstate] => HY000 [error] => No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement ) ) [sqlstate] => HY000 [id] => 6 )`

Comment: If you changed paid '?' to '0', have you removed the third 'i' from the end of your paramstring? The error that you've received regarding to paramstring and parameters count

Comment: FIXED!!! Just had to remove the `i` from `bind_param()`  It now inserts the data to the table.  Thanks for your help and talking me through it Vahe!!

Comment: see my last comment :)

Comment: Hahah, on the same page!